# Listar 5 objetos de um List

Tags: java, mysql, aplicação-web

Estou montando um painel em que deveria mostrar 5 produtos, por exemplo, no index de uma página, entretanto apenas consigo carregar todos os objetos que estão salvos no BD, e não consigo pensar numa forma de como fazer isso, qualquer alternativa serviria, pelo DAO, carregando em uma classe ou mesmo no front. Teriam alguma solução?

Front:

```
    <c:forEach items="${dao.listarPlat('PS4')}" var="p">
                                    <div class="col-md-3 produto well i2">
                                            <img class="img" src="img/${p.foto1}" title="" alt="">
                                            ${p.titulo}<br>${p.plataforma}
                                                R$
                                                <f:formatNumber minFractionDigits="2" currencySymbol="R$">
                                                    ${p.preco}
                                                </f:formatNumber>
                                        <button class="btn btn-success">Comprar</button>
                                    </div>    
                                </c:forEach>
```

DAO:

```
    public List<Produto> findProdutosPlat(String plataforma) {
    try {
        Query query = em.createQuery("select p from Produto as p where p.plataforma like :plataforma");
        query.setParameter("plataforma", plataforma + "%");
        List<Produto> produtos = query.getResultList();
        return produtos;
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}
```

CtrlProduto:

```
    public List<Produto> listarPlat(String dados) throws Exception {
    ProdutoDAO dao = new ProdutoDAO();
    return dao.findProdutosPlat(dados);
}
```

A solução pelo foi adicionar ao DAO o *.setMaxResults(5)*, ficando assim:

```
    public List<Produto> findProdutosMenu(String plataforma) {
    try {
        Query query = em.createQuery("select p from Produto as p where p.plataforma like :plataforma");
        query.setParameter("plataforma", plataforma + "%");
        query.setMaxResults(5);
        List<Produto> produtos = query.getResultList();
        return produtos;
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Qual o SGBD? MySql? SqlServer?

Comment: Estou utilizando o mysql, administro pelo PHPMyAdmin

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbrg.html, usando o `setMaxResult` na sua `query`, funciona?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado dito e feito. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Pronto, agora poste a resposta explicando como você conseguiu solucionar o problema =] assim alguém que tenha tido o seu mesmo problema vai poder consultar na resposta a solução